# how to sort the data from firebase? inside a flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to sort data which i get from firebase database below is the code I tried but this throws an error:

> (NoSuchMethodError: Class "String" has no instance method 'orderBy').

What is the best practice to sort the data?

```
dateTime: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['dateTime'].orderBy('createdAt', descending: true),
```

Below I am adding the code from CrudMethods.

```
  getData() async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection('PlasmaRequests').orderBy('createdAt', descending: true).snapshots();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort after retrieving, this code:

```
snapshot.data.documents[index].data['dateTime']
```

means you retrieved the snapshot, and you are getting the field `dateTime` which is of type `String`.

---

You use `orderBy()` when you perform the query:

```
void getData() async {
var result = await Firestore.instance
  .collection("myColName")
  .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
  .getDocuments();
}
```

Check the docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: Hi thank you. I am new to development its been not more then a month. I made changes to getData as per your suggested code but no data is being retrieved and the page is empty. I am really struck at this from couple of days.

Comment: where are u using `getData()`?

Comment: in My crudmethods. I just added that code below my first code.

Comment: did u get data before?

Comment: My code was not well formatted in question before. I made changes now. I have sent a tweet as well for guidance on this please check.